# How to use tikzmark inside tikz-cd?

Tags: tikz-cd, tikzmark

I want to use tikzmark in tikzcd. 
However, even the following sample returns errors

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd} 
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
\tikzmark{u1}A & B\\
C & \tikzmark{u2}D
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[->] (u1) edge (u2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The error report is

> Package tikz Error: Cannot parse this coordinate. \tikzmark{u1}A
>
> Package tikz Error: Cannot parse this coordinate. C & \tikzmark{u2}D
>
> Package pgf Error: No shape named u1 is known. \draw[->] (u1)
>
> Package pgf Error: No shape named u1 is known. \draw[->] (u1) edge
>   (u2)
>
> Package pgf Error: No shape named u2 is known. \draw[->] (u1) edge
>   (u2)
>
> Package pgf Error: No shape named u2 is known. \draw[->] (u1) edge
>   (u2)
>
> Package pgf Error: No shape named u1 is known. \draw[->] (u1) edge
>   (u2)
>
> Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.

**How to fix this kind of errors?**

**Update:**
I have tried this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd} 
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[remember picture]
aaaaaa\subnode{u1}{A} & B\\
C & \subnode{u2}{D}ddddddd
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[->] (u1) edge (u2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd} 
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[remember picture]
aaaaaa\tikzmarknode{u1}{A} & B\\
C & \tikzmarknode{u2}{D}ddddddd
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[->] (u1) edge (u2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But none of them put the arrow in correct location.

**Update:**
The \tikzmarknode command does work correctly if I use LuaLaTex instead of XeLaTeX.

Comment: You don't. Just add `remember picture` to the `tikzcd` and refer to the nodes with `(\tikzcdmatrixname-1-1)` and so on.

Comment: Note that xelatex has known issues with positioning, and so with tikzmark.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. However, the answer by LoopSpace is clearly better, Could you please accept it instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Note: I agree with marmot that for *this* particular case I wouldn't use tikzmark, but I get that it is a simple example and it reveals a bug in tikzmark.)

It would appear that when I modified tikzmark to make it possible to use inside tikzpictures, then I inadvertently broke the ability to use it inside a node (though I'm not sure if that was ever a recommended use!).  A node is inside a tikzpicture but should be treated as if it weren't.  My current test for whether the tikzmark is inside a tikzpicture doesn't pick up on this.  Here's the corrected test:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/458387/86}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd} 
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\makeatletter

\def\tikzmark{%
  \ifx\pgfpictureid\@undefined
  \let\tikzmark@next=\tikzmark@outside
  \else
  \relax
  \ifx\scope\tikz@origscope\relax
  \let\tikzmark@next=\tikzmark@outside
  \else
  \let\tikzmark@next=\tikzmark@inside
  \fi
  \fi
  \tikzmark@next%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
\tikzmark{u1}A & B\\
C & \tikzmark{u2}D
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[->] (pic cs:u1) -- (pic cs:u2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I've uploaded this to [github](https://github.com/loopspace/tikzmark) and will send it off to CTAN once the amazing testing team of marmot has answered a few questions to check that I haven't broken something else!

Comment: Great! That's what I was hoping for! The marmot testing team used this great package in several answers and everything worked absolutely smoothly!

Comment: My new maxim: never trust anything until it has been stress tested by a marmot.

Answer (score 4):

**REVISED ANSWER**: I could get `tikzmark` to collaborate with `tikz-cd` by switching to `\tikzmarknode`. More precisely, if I rewrite [cfr's nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/287727/54169) to become

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd,amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
  x \in \tikzmarknode{u1}{U} \subseteq M \arrow{r}{f} & f(x) \in V \subseteq 
  \tikzmarknode{n}{N} \arrow{d}{\psi} \\
  \phi(x) \in \tikzmarknode{u2}{\phi(U)} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{m} \arrow{r}{\psi f \phi^{-1}} & \psi(f(x)) \in \psi(V) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}
\end{tikzcd}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
  \draw [->] (u1) edge ["$\phi$", right] (u2.north -| u1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

which might be what you are after.

Let me also mention that for your above example you may not use `\tikzmark` since you have the objects already in Ti*k*Z nodes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[remember picture]
A & B\\
C & D
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[->] (\tikzcdmatrixname-1-1) edge (\tikzcdmatrixname-2-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What I mean is I cannot use tikzmark commands inside a tikzcd environment: as in my sample shows the command \tikzmark just cause "Cannot parse this coordinate" error.

Comment: @Gau-Syu Yes, that's not surprising since you are essentially nesting `tikzpicture`s by doing this, which should be avoided.

Comment: What makes me confuse is that there are some answers in Tex.SE using tikzmark inside tikzcd, for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/287727/54169 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/176572/54169

Comment: @Gau-Syu Yes, but it is clearly stated that you need to use `\subnode` then. I believe that the thing above is simpler. (As I said, I really love tikzmark, but would not use it here.)

Comment: No, the second one only used \tikzmark. But I have tried to copy the codes and got error reports. The first one using \subnode doesn't work either: the arrow just located at wrong place. My purpose is to use tikzmark in tikz-cd as in the those two examples. The sample in my question is just to point where the error located.

Comment: @Gau-Syu Even if I knew how to use tikzmark here, I would not post the solution because it will inevitably be fragile. May I ask why you want to use tikzmark here? (And do you know that there is an update which has the super useful command `\tikzmarknode` in it?)

Comment: my original purpose is to get an arrow from a specified part (i.e. a subnode) in a node to another. For example, in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/287727/54169.

Comment: The \tikzmarknode doesn't cause error. However, as \subnode, it doesn't remember the location in tikzcd environment correctly.

Comment: @Gau-Syu I see! I just realized that the old answers do not compile any more. That is, you may have found an unexpected "feature" of the updated tikzmark library. (To it's defense, I should add that it might never be meant to be used like this, but I am not sure if this statement is true since I know that this capability was advertized in several answers, one of which I used.)

Comment: @Gau-Syu I am sorry, originally I did not realize that there are issues with the updated version of tikzmark. The good news is that `\tikzmarknode`, which is a new command that has been added, seems to harmonize with `tikz-cd`. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @marmot See my answer.  Yet again, you've tracked down a bug in tikzmark.