# Tikzcd: point to specific line using tikzmark

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd, tikzmark

I'd like to add in tikzcd some arrows pointing to a specific line (here the line JKL). However my code always point to the top of the cell (when it's even producing a meaningfull output):

[image]

I'm not sure why, but tikzmarknodes were reported to work [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/458387/how-to-use-tikzmark-inside-tikz-cd).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd,amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,quotes}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  point line/.style={
    to path={
      (#1-|{\tikztostart.east}) -- (#1-|{\tikztotarget.west})
      \tikztonodes
    }
  }
}

\begin{tikzcd}
  A \rar[point line=myline] & |[fill=green]| \tiny \begin{tabular}{@{}L@{}}
                                  ABC\\
                                  DEF\\
                                  GHI\\
                                  \tikzmarknode{myline}{JKL}\end{tabular}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd,amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,quotes}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  point line/.style={
    to path={
      (#1-|{\tikztostart.east}) -- (#1-|{\tikztotarget.west})
      \tikztonodes
    }
  }
}

\begin{tikzcd}[overlay, remember picture]
  A \rar[point line=myline] & |[fill=green]| \tiny \begin{tabular}{@{}L@{}}
                                  ABC\\
                                  DEF\\
                                  GHI\\
                                  \tikzmarknode{myline}{JKL}\end{tabular}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image: Arrow pointing to line in array]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately adding `[overlay, remember picture]` has another problem: the figure now takes zero height and width, and overlaps the text around. But adding only `remember picture` gives the appropriate result (compile twice or the result is really ugly, with an image going even in a different page)! Thanks a lot!